# Accessing DB without knowing it's password?

Tags: mysql, hosting

Being a Junior Web Dev, I'm not too familiar with creating websites with Database Interaction beyond the usual localhost and simple local registration.

But, for instance, how do Web Devs, in a Web Department, connect to a company's DB, without the need of having separate User accounts for each dev in the company? It would be silly otherwise.

Comment: This is not related to PHP, please only use relevant tags.

Comment: a production environment uses its own credentials. Dev's have their own localhost environments to develop on not to risk production. A good company will never give production credentials to the junior

Comment: There usually _are_ separate accounts in the database server, but not for each individual developer. From my experience, usually a database account is created to be used by an application, and that account is granted the necessary privileges to the schema/functions used by that application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a security policy decision, there are no hard and fast rules. A production environment may have a single shared username/password, or it might have a bunch of accounts.

This is entirely at the discretion of the devops/administration team.